# KMLViewer Question

Tags: ios, mkmapview, overlays

This is my first post and I am admittedly over my head, but I do need some help.

I downloaded Apple's KMLViewer example to look at overlays in maps. After getting it to work, as part of my "investigation," I then added the line

```
map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

right after the  line

```
[super viewDidLoad];
```

I know I didn't have too, but I had another project that required programmatically creating a MKMapView and I wanted to verify the approach on a simpler, working program.

The result was the KMLViewer compiled and executed with no errors, but no longer showed the overlays created by the kml files. If the line was removed, the overlays showed up again.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The map variable in KMLViewer is declared as an IBOutlet and is connected to the MKMapView in the xib.  By re-creating it, the new instance is no longer connected to the one in the xib.

The overlays are probably not showing because:

- the delegate on the new instance is not set (so viewForOverlay, etc. won't get called)
- the new map isn't added as a subview

So if you added the following two lines after the alloc+init, it should start working again:

```
map.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:map];
```

However, the MKMapView in the xib will still be there underneath the new map instance.